# Twitter and FB integration to iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Does anybody know a good framework for twitter and FB integration to iPhone app which support location sharing as well ? I tried out sharekit but it seems it does not support geoaware tweets... any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS5 has a native Twitter integration and Facebook has a native iOS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, year I am trying out the FB SDK now. But I was hoping for straight forward API like sharekit which would have made my work lot easier. :( And we are targeting iOs 4.0 upwards so I think I may have to use the Twitter SDK as well.

Comment: No Offence..but if everything comes readily like drag and drop ang Booom..Than whats the purpose of Software Engineers?

Comment: Haha yeah I know. U got me there. May be I should add this functionality to sharekit. Make life easier on someone else. Cheers man !

Comment: Take a look at this list of Twitter libraries for Obj-C/Cocoa https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#objectivec

Comment: Thanks mate , One little question I am not FB user so sorry for the ignorance. lets say we post something on the wall  can we have the post location there as well ?

Comment: Check out the Graph API docs, it says yes you can ;-) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I saw that mate but what is puzzling me is the part that says "object containing id and name of Page associated with this location". Does that mean the place aka location must already have a FB Page ?

Comment: I can't say this for sure but it sounds like that's the case, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](http://buildinternet.com/2011/10/tweet-sheet-creating-a-popup-tweet-in-ios-5/) to do Twitter integration. So Integrating Twitter in `> iOS 5.0` is quite simple and does show a nice dialog:

[image: Twitter example]